# How to loop a function involving subsets of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, loops

I'm a new R user and I'm having some difficulty making a loop. I've made a simpler version of my data below to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
#My Data:

set.seed(123)
x <- runif(10,1,100)
y <- sample(LETTERS[1:3],10,replace=TRUE)

#Then I made subsets of my data in a data frame: 

df <- data.frame(x,y)
A <- subset(df, y=='A')
B <- subset(df, y=='B')
C <- subset(df, y=='C')

#I'm able to get the max and min of each subset like this: 

print(paste('A Max = ',max(A$x))); print(paste('A Min = ',min(A$x)))
print(paste('B Max = ',max(B$x))); print(paste('B Min = ',min(B$x)))
print(paste('C Max = ',max(C$x))); print(paste('C Min = ',min(C$x)))
```

I want to create a loop that will find the max and min of each subset automatically. Ideally, so it will print all of the results at once and preferably with a label like "Max = ". Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You typically wouldn't use loops in R for something like this. Either use `dplyr::group_by` or you can `split()` and `Map()` with base R.

Comment: An option would be `by(df, df$y, function(x) setNames(range(x$x), c("Min", "Max")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You can use `library(dplyr)` and use these lines of code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarise(min = min(x),
            max = max(x))
```

To understand the code read some introductions to the tidyverse, e.g. [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction.html) or some of the links [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/learn/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Those links are very helpful. I figured a loop would be easiest, but this seems a little more straightforward. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to do this too especially if you have a very large data.  Here are few: `for`-loop, `sapply`, and `tapply`

#### for loop

```
for (i in LETTERS[1:3]) {
  cat(i, 'Max =', max(df$x[df$y == i]), '\n')
  cat(i, 'Min =', min(df$x[df$y == i]), '\n')
}

A Max = 94.10626 
A Min = 53.28244 
B Max = 88.41872 
B Min = 79.04221 
C Max = 46.20486 
C Min = 5.510093
```

#### sapply

```
invisible(
  sapply(LETTERS[1:3], function(i) {
    cat(i, 'Max =', max(df$x[df$y == i]), '\n')
    cat(i, 'Min =', min(df$x[df$y == i]), '\n')
  })
)

A Max = 94.10626 
A Min = 53.28244 
B Max = 88.41872 
B Min = 79.04221 
C Max = 46.20486 
C Min = 5.510093
```

#### tapply

```
min = with(df, tapply(x, y, min))
max = with(df, tapply(x, y, max))
```

Comment: I would say introducing `get()` to new users is not a good idea. This will certainly lead to problems later on. Better to encourage them to use named lists and split/apply strategies since that's more consistent with the R philosophy.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how a loop would work in this case! I am not a huge fan of loops, but I didn't realize there were other relatively simple ways to do this. I'll probably try one of the other suggestions, but it's great to know I could make a loop if necessary. And thank you MrFlick for the warning, I certainly appreciate the words of caution. I realized very quickly how easy it is to screw things up in R.

Comment: Agree.  Fixed the `for` loop and `sapply()` to get rid of `get()`.  Also provided another way to do this using `tapply()`